# Is defacing own posts worth a mod flag?

Tags: discussion, questions, vandalism

Some users engage in destructive behaviours against their own post(s).
They may want to dissociate the post(s) from their account, or are simply going in a frustrated rampage.

This kind of defacing is generally very quickly noticed by users (and bots) and cancelled in the next few seconds with a rollback. The post would also probably get some downvotes and comments.

From there, in the following scenarios, should further action in the form of a mod flag be taken?

- User defaced one post, did not engage in a rollback war
- User defaced multiple posts, did not engage in a rollback war
- User defaced one post, engaged a rollback war
- User defaced multiple posts, engaged a rollback war

---

This has been asked [in a previous meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302819/what-to-do-with-a-user-defacing-or-even-spamming-his-own-questions), but the community accepted answers differ.

Comment: I would flag in any situation bar the first - roll back one, but if there are multiple posts or they do it again, involve the mods. There are also scripts in place to detect e.g. users deleting many of their own posts.

Comment: Your first scenario isn't worth mod time- If they only defaced one post and stopped and didn't continue the behavior, especially if it was stopped by a comment by a community member... Not worth bugging mods over. For the last two scenarios, pretty sure an auto-flag is cast when a rollback war ensues- I could be wrong there. Even still, it could be helpful, and is especially so in the last scenario, to flag for mod attention and explain (with links to the affected posts.) For the second scenario... I'm not sure myself. A mod flag probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: *"however the accepted answers differ"* **Accepted** answers are like Immortals: There Can Be Only One. Did it differ with itself? (*"Do I contradict myself? Very well, then I contradict myself, I am large, I contain multitudes."*)

Comment: see also: [Why was BalusC temporarily suspended from SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/839601)

Comment: Defacin' your own posts?  [That's a paddlin'](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/thats-a-paddlin).

Comment: @Sabito,
*Just because 'rollback war' words appear in a post doesn't mean that the post is about rollback wars.*
That's true in general.
And I agree that the tag [vandalism] is a good and relevant tag for this question.
When it comes to the [rollback-wars] tag, I respectfully disagree with you.
I consider this question to be one of the most important Meta Stack Overflow
questions on [rollback-wars], maybe ***the*** most important question of all
on this topic.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If the user defaces multiple posts we get an automatic flag.

If the user engages in a rollback war we get an automatic flag.

To take your points in order:

> - User defaced one post, did not engage in a rollback war

No flag, but nothing for a moderator to do.

> - User defaced multiple posts, did not engage in a rollback war

Auto flag, but nothing for a moderator to do other than clear the flag as the edits have already been reverted by regular users.

> - User defaced one post, engaged a rollback war

Auto flag, moderator may lock the post.

> - User defaced multiple posts, engaged a rollback war

Two auto flags, moderator may suspend user.

Therefore you can see that all the cases where a moderator might need to intervene are already catered for with automatically generated flags,

Therefore, you should do nothing.

In particular you should move on should a rollback war looks like it's going to start - i.e. the OP has rolled back the rollback. We'll get notifications and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: The only thing I'd add is that a custom moderator flag may be warranted if the user defaced their question in an offensive or insulting way. Even for something that users are able to roll back, we may want to message and / or suspend the user for this. Also, even with the system flags, additional custom flags can move things up our queue for cases where we may need to act quickly on someone who is defacing a lot of posts. They're not needed, but may be welcome to draw extra attention to particularly bad incidents.

Comment: It requires two sides to make a rollback war. I'd rather flag a post manually for an administrator to take action than be one side of the rollback war triggering an automatic flag.

Comment: Also, avoiding rolling back because you think the original author would cause a rollback war is entirely counterproductive. The rollback doesn't happen _and_ the rollback war then never happens. So everybody loses except the defacer.

Comment: @kasperd It takes one party.  Party A edits the post to deface it.  You rollback.  There is *no rollback war*.  Once party A rollsback your rollback, then begin the rollback wars have, and it was begun by only one party.  The next rollback (by you, or someone else) continues the war, and instead of it happening, moderators need to arrive.  This (apparently?) results in an auto-flag, so you can just ignore the rollback of the rollback and let the moderator handle it.

Comment: Is this true in the case of users with < 2k rep? My understanding is that you don't get the rollback option until you get to 2k rep, so any rollback would actually be a manual edit to what it was beforehand. Does the software pick up on that, or would a flag be necessary in this case?

Comment: @R_Kapp - I'm pretty sure you can rollback edits on your own posts.

Comment: @ChrisF But even if they can rollback edits to their own post we cannot count on them doing so. I think I have seen users vandalize their own post and then after it was rolled back they would vandalize it again a little bit differently. If I see that I would flag it for a moderator because I cannot know for sure whether an automatic flag is raised in that case.

Comment: Does it count as a rollback war (raise an auto-flag) in the following scenario? User vandlizes post → other user rolls back the edit → user edits their post to vandalizes again (not a rollback) → other user rolls back the edit again.

Comment: @TinyGiant yes.

Comment: @ChrisF sorry the answer to this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290297/how-much-change-to-the-question-is-too-much (I thought I supplied a link) :D

Comment: How does the system tell if a user defaced a post to auto flag it?