# Flag vandalized posts for moderation even if no one took action?

Tags: discussion, edits, moderation

First of all I am aware of the [automatic flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag) raised if a user vandalizes multiple posts and/or gets involved in a rollback war. However I recently stumbled across a quite simple [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251528/using-boolean-to-print-invalid-commands-in-java) which was still fun to answer but a couple of hours later was rendered almost completely useless by the owner.

However no one seemed to bother and I am relative new to the community myself so I didn't take action either.

A couple of days later the same user did it again with another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286612/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-error-occurs) and again no one seemed to care. But it bothered me. Not only because I participated with my answers but it had lowered the quality of the questions quite a lot.

In my opinion they should be rolled back to their original state which includes the Code since it is almost mandatory to get the gist of the question. Also such a post could be used as a [broken window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) which could lead to an overall decrease of quality.

Anyway just recently it [happened again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409243/multi-class-listtodo-using-arrays-arraylist-error) by another user but this time a moderator immediatly rolled back and locked the post. So I asked myself if I should flag the two questions I've mentioned above for need of moderation since I feel that they do not belong here in their current form.

Or should I just stop caring and hope they'll be forgotten and ignored?

Comment: I would usually roll back myself, but since the user has a history of doing it, I think it's better if you use a custom flag and explain to the moderator what is happening. // Please do not "stop caring". We need to keep enforcing quality-control on the site. :)

Comment: It is easy to misinterpret "not noticing" as "not caring".  It usually takes a contributor to the Q+A to notice.  You.  If you can't click rollback yourself then simply ask a moderator to do it for you.  These kind of destructive edits are always rolled-back.  Notifying the user that his behavior is being discussed at meta tends to be useful, done.

Comment: Just don't forget to specify you can't rollback yourself (being below 2k rep) in the mod flag. Mods don't get to see all the information at first so make your flag as usefull and complete as you can.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As Hans points out in the comments above, the core issue is visibility. Moderators can't be everywhere on the site, so we rely on people to let us know when things are going off the rails.

Bhargav happened to be there right as your last case was going down, and took action on what he saw. The others weren't flagged, so we didn't know they were getting vandalized. The automatic system flags only kick in after multiple rollbacks, which hadn't yet happened there.

If you do see a user vandalizing their posts, we really do appreciate a custom flag to that effect. We will roll back one-time edits and provide a gentle warning about the nature of the site. If they are mass-editing or deleting their posts, we typically will send them a message requesting they explain what they're doing and suspend their account for a day to prevent further vandalism (suspension lifted if they can provide a good reason for their behavior or promise to stop).

This is an unfortunately common occurrence around the end of a school term, as students all of a sudden realize their professors know how to use Google. We try to deal with the cases we come across naturally or by system flags, but we rely on the community to bring others to our attention. Any help you can provide in identifying mass-vandalism of posts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yup, that was what happened in the last case. Both the posts mentioned were reported in [chat as vandalism](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=42459585#42459585), but no one was there to roll it back. I was around [when the second was reported](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=42591452#42591452), which is why I was able to catch it.

Comment: Is the edit history of each post indexed by Google? If so, users trying to get away with stuff like this so their teachers/lecturers don't find out that it's not their own work would be foolish at best (even if their posts are not rolled back).

Comment: @cybermonkey Unfortunately, no. Fortunately, [so] doesn't allow that, and such cases are very regularly detected (there are bots for that too)

Comment: @user202729 I don't think you understand my question, I'm asking if `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/[postid]/revisions` has a robots.txt which denies search engines to crawl the post revision history page.

Comment: @cybermonkey why ask when [you can look](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt)?

Comment: anyways, `which denies search engines to crawl the post revision history page` why should it be?