# Shouldn't we ban a user for spamming suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

When I got [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13399463) in Suggested Edits Review queue, I thought it is a Review Audit. But unfortunately I proved wrong for the first time in Suggested Edits!

However, after some more review, I got [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13399458) from the same user, then [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13399459).

So, should not we ban [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6735545/jau-lee) as he is vandalizing in the site?

Tips: These edits could be added in review audit!

#### Why is it not a duplicate of [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users) mentioned?

The user is not experienced here, rather he is comparatively new. In my view, it is opened to do vandalizing. In the provided question, the main thing is tag-only edit, which is considerable, but here, the main thing is vandalizing. So, two cases are completely different and should be handled differently. On the other hand, **the user involved that question [responded in the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314620/3555000) of that question and the issue is dealt by a moderator.** But what about the involved user in this question?

As far I know, vandalizing is handled very strictly in SO and the user did vandalizing here.

However, [other possible duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306820/is-defacing-own-posts-worth-a-mod-flag) is some how related except about own post.

Comment: @Braiam The user is not 2k here, rather he is comparatively new. In my view, it is opened to do spamming. In the provided question, the main thing is tag-only edit, which is considerable, but here, the main thing is spamming. So, two cases are completely different and should be handled differently.

Comment: I am pretty sure, the Stack Overlow team implemented some automatic process for banning users, that are doing edits, which are rejected as destructive.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I also believe that. But I thought, what about knowing the actual punishment process from a moderator?

Comment: Only <2k users are able to suggest edits.

Comment: @Braiam I meant the user is comparatively new and not experienced like that question.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Could you please help me to understand how this question is a possible duplicate of the question you mentioned?

Comment: The user actually wasn't spamming, because he wasn't trying to promote himself or a product.  Instead, he was defacing / vandalizing his post, both the question (rolled back by Lauren) and all of the answers (which you have linked).  The duplicate that I suggested asks a very similar question, about what to do about defacing posts.  The first sentence of the answer on the suggested duplicate actually does answer what I understand your question to be: "If the user defaces multiple posts we get an automatic flag."  This will result in the appropriate action, possibly even a ban.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Did you mean all rejected suggested edits are considered as defacing / vandalizing ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  The edits each replaced valid content with gibberish.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I am not agreeing without you, but leaving it for now. However, could you please explain why [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302819/what-to-do-with-a-user-defacing-or-even-spamming-his-own-questions#comment235500_302819) by a moderator if auto-flagging is turned on as described?: *If you notice a user defacing/destroying their own content (as is happening here) then yes, flag for a moderator and explain your suspicions. We can then take measures to prevent it continuing while we reach out to the user to establish what's going on.*

Comment: The comment referred to a user defacing his own post.  An edit to your own content doesn't go through the review queues, and so won't trigger automatic flags for defacing multiple posts.  The situation in your question would trigger those automatic flags, as the user had 3 posts rejected for defacement.  Even if there *happen to be automatic flags raised*, you won't know, so the appropriate action is to also raise a mod flag, as Ed described in his answer below.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill Thanks for your time. * the appropriate action is to also raise a mod flag* is a good conclusion and a different information than other posts.

Comment: It is and pretty well always has been more correct to use moderator flags when dealing with a specific users actions. No one one wants to be called out in public, whether they are in the right or not. We don't need public shaming, we need problems solved efficiently. Only moderators can effectively deal with situations like this,

Comment: @TinyGiant Good Thinking. I appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I think this all started with my rollback and the subsequent comment I left. I didn't think that it would get this out of hand (it was late and they didn't have any other posts), so I didn't flag (I thought that the user could be taught the right way; apparently not). An error in judgement on my part, sorry everyone. On the other hand, that rollback inspired me to post [this meta FR](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/6083675).

Comment: @Laurel It looks like the damage had already been done when you did your rollback; the OP had made all of the vandalism edits prior to that, and all within a 2-minute period.  I don't think that you should have raised a flag at that point, because you were able to correctly and definitively handle the situation right there with your rollback and comment.  It was only when manetsus found the 3 reviews that the pattern emerged, and that's when a moderator needed to get involved.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill You're right, I did the rollback minutes *after* the edits were suggested. That makes me feel a lot better (I was thinking it was some type of reaction to what I said). If I realized there was behavior outside the self-vandalism, I likely would have flagged (and rejected the edits, if available). In any case, self-vandalism is difficult to detect, so I'm glad I caught it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thank you for alerting us to this situation. It has been handled.

In the future, the best way to call this to our attention is via the flagging system. Asking a question on Meta will get a response, but it's not the best approach.

The better approach is to raise a custom moderator flag on an affected post and describe the problem. Providing links, as you did in this question, is essential to a useful flag for this kind of behavior.

Also, as mentioned in the comments: what this user was doing was technically not spamming (promoting a product or site without disclosure). He or she was simply defacing posts, replacing real content with gibberish. That's not spamming, but it's still very bad behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as far I know, the custom flagging queue is very long. Some of my flag aged away (Though I am telling about more than year ago). Could you please inform us what is the length of custom flagging queue now? Note that, the news of very long queue is mentioned by a moderator in some post.

Comment: @manetsus AFAiK custom mods flags don't age away. I'm pretty sure that they only aged away flags I have (last time I checked) were all close flags from before I could vote to close questions.

Comment: @manetsus The queue is... painful. It's currently sitting around 1200 flags, of which almost 300 are custom flags. That said, the system tries to sort posts so that we see the best and most urgent flags first. We tend to get to issues like this one pretty quickly, especially if more than one user flags a problem post. Over the last month, the average flag-handling time across all types of flags is under 12 hours. Many get handled in seconds; some take much longer.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks once again for the info and your time. I got it properly.  I have replaced all word 'spamming' with 'vandalizing' in my post.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's correct; custom flags don't age away. There are a few types of flags that can age away. Currently, those are: offensive and spam flags on posts, offensive flags on comments, close votes for migration, and close/open votes and flags. You can read more on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/238426).

Comment: @manetsus Glad to help! Thanks for letting us know about the problem.

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks for confirming that *custom flags don't age away*. All of my aged away flags are closing question. Really proud of you.

Comment: In other words, there is no automatic process for banning users that are doing multiple bad edits, which are rejected as destructive?

Comment: @Christian if enough suggested edits are rejected then the user is suspended automatically from suggested edits for two days